# Hibernate Criteria, createAlias() If Alias is Null

Tags: java, hibernate, alias, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

In the code below..
There are two Alias as `Entity Object`  Reference.
Sometimes `"caseStage" as stage` can be `null` in Database.
When `"caseStage"` is null I want `stage.name` value as an empty `String` or something customized like `"---"` etc.

```
session.createCriteria(CaseMasterPO.class)
       .createAlias("branch", "br")     // BranchPO.class
       .createAlias("caseStage", "stage") // CaseStagePO.class
       .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
          .add(Projections.property("caseCode"))
          .add(Projections.property("br.zoneCode"))
          .add(Projections.property("stage.name")) // Problem, when stage == null
       )
       .add(Restrictions.eq("caseCode", caseCode)).uniqueResult();
```

Comment: I usually use coalesce(stage.name, '---') in HQL, so is there any mechanism for Criteria Query ?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing .. please explain that ??

Comment: How you display your objects on the screen shouldn't be decided and specified in a database query. Modify your presentation-layer code to display whatever you want in case the value is null.

Comment: Can't you just use Projections.sqlProjection instead?

Comment: @Zulfi, 
In the above code there is a `Projections` with property name `stage.name`. I do not get the rows when`stage` is `null`. in database.

Comment: can you also post your entity classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN to alias function

.createAlias("branch", "br" , CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
.createAlias("caseStage", "stage", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

Comment: Dear bro, is there any way to use `CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN` with `DetachedCriteria` ?

Answer (score 2):

[@Koti Eswar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7204153/koti-eswar) answer is right, but it's deprecated now.

It's should be done like this:

```
        join('branch', JoinType.LEFT)
        createAlias('branch', 'br')
```

Tested in Grails 3.3.5

Comment: Currently I am using `JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN`